# Why can I not assign NULL value to this pointer array element?

Tags: c, arrays, undefined-behavior

I am still new to programming in C. I am sorry if this kind of question has already been asked, I did not really know what to search for exactly.

As an exercise I am programming a dictionary. The user should be able to add, print, and remove words in this stage of the exercise. Words are stored in a character pointer array called 'dict'. The function 'removeWord'  should make sure the word to be removed is replaced by the last word in the array 'dict'. So the last word should be copied to the element that has to be removed and subsequently the last element should be removed (i.e. assigned the value NULL to). When the word to be removed is the last word in the array 'dict' it should also be removed.

The program stops running when any word in the array 'dict' is removed except for the last one in the array. When any word except for the last one is removed I want to assign the value NULL to the last element.

I hope my question is clear. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

```
int numberOfWordsInDict(char **dict)
{
    int i,cnt=0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(dict[i]!=NULL)
        {
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    return cnt;
}

void addWord(char **dict, char *word)
{
    int i=0;
    if(numberOfWordsInDict(dict)==10)
    {
        printf("Dictionary is already full!\n");
    }
    int k=numberOfWordsInDict(dict);
    dict[k]=(char*)malloc((strlen(word)+1)*sizeof(char));

    strcpy(dict[k],word);
}


void printDict(char **dict)
{
    int i=0;
    printf("Dictionary:\n");
    if(numberOfWordsInDict(dict)==0)
    {
        printf("The dictionary is empty.\n");

    }else
    {
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
        printf("- %s\n", dict[i]);
        }
    }
}

void removeWord(char **dict, char *word)
{
    int i,j=0;
    int swapped=0;
    j=numberOfWordsInDict(dict);
    for(i=0;i<j;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(dict[i],word)==0 && swapped==0)
        {
        swapped=1;
        //strcpy(dict[i],dict[j-1]);
        dict[j-1] = NULL;
        }
    }

}
```

at dict[j-1] the error occurs.

```
int main()
{
    char wordToBeAdded[36]={};
    char wordToBeRemoved[36]={};
    char *dict[10]={};
    char operation;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Command (a/p/r/q): ");
        scanf(" %c", &operation);

        switch(operation)
        {
            case 'a':
                printf("Add a word: ");
                scanf(" %s", &wordToBeAdded);
                addWord(dict,wordToBeAdded);
                break;

            case 'p':
                printDict(dict);
                break;

            case 'r':
                printf("Remove a word: ");
                scanf(" %s", &wordToBeRemoved);
                removeWord(dict,wordToBeRemoved);
                break;

            case 'q':
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Christiaan de Leijer what error?

Comment: *at `dict[j-1]` the error occurs.*.... what error?

Comment: well because of that piece of code the program stops working. There is not really an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you access the last item of your dict after it has been removed. When you access the last item in the dict to compare it to the word, it has already been set to null. As Weather Vane commented, you could break when you find the word. That would prevent you from accessing this last item when it has been removed.

```
void removeWord(char **dict, char *word)
{
    int i,j=0;
    int swapped=0;
    j=numberOfWordsInDict(dict);
    for(i=0;i<j;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(dict[i],word)==0 && swapped==0)
        {
            swapped=1;
            //strcpy(dict[i],dict[j-1]);
            dict[j-1] = NULL;
        }
    }

}
```

So when i=j-1 `if(strcmp(dict[i],word)==0 && swapped==0)` this will try to dereference the pointer that you just set to null.

Comment: Okay, so the problem is that by using strcmp() I am trying to dereference pointers that have NULL values.

But still one question about this. Why does the following code not give any errors when compiling? 

    int main()
    {
        char *dict[10]={};
        char *word="hello";
        strcmp(dict[1],word);
    }

Comment: Okay, so I just found out by using this code that the code will give errors when you are trying to use the value of strcmp or putting it in if statements etc... 


int main()
{
    int a,b,c=0;
    char *dict[10]={};
    char *word="hello";
    char *word2="bla";
    char *word3="hello";
    a=strcmp(word,word2);
    b=strcmp(word,word3);
    c=strcmp(dict[2],word);

    printf("\n%d\n",a);

    printf("\n%d\n",b);

    printf("\n%d\n",c);
}

Comment: I understand it now. I am new to this forum and I don't know how to put code in these comments properly (sorry for that). Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. If you have solved your problem it would be great if you marked an answer so that people know that the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not going to removing any words: as you never change the value of variable `j`, what it does is just repeatedly set the last pointer to NULL, which is nothing about remove an specific item from the string list.

Besides that, your code did not free the space of any removed words.

In addition, your code is bad at the scope of software engineering, which should:

- Collect constants to one same location, such as `#define DICT_MAX_SIZE 10`instead of writing value everywhere.
- Do **NOT** use meaningless variable names such as `i j k` when there are better choices which can demonstrate its function clearly, such as `dict_size`, `i_head`, `i_tail`, etc..

Comment: It do not see why the last pointer is repeatedly set to NULL because it happens only when one of the words in dict is equal to the word that should be removed.  Yes you are right, my code is bad for software engineering. I study electrical engineering. For now I just want to get this program working. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in when you iterate through the table and try to read from the pointer with value of NULL.

When you delete the last word, you will never get there. But if you delete not the last one when you iterate through the table you dereference it.

I am not going to change **logic of your code (and do not check if it does what the function name promises)** - just sanitize the use of pointer by adding the check if it is not NULL

```
void printDict(char **dict)
{
    int i=0;
    printf("Dictionary:\n");
    if(numberOfWordsInDict(dict)==0)
    {
        printf("The dictionary is empty.\n");

    }else
    {
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
        if(dict[i] != NULL) printf("- %s\n", dict[i]);
        }
    }
}


void removeWord(char **dict, char *word)
{
    int i,j=0;
    int swapped=0;
    j=numberOfWordsInDict(dict);
    for(i=0;i<j;i++)
    {
        if(dict[i] != NULL) 
           if(strcmp(dict[i],word)==0 && swapped==0)
           {
           swapped=1;
           //strcpy(dict[i],dict[j-1]);
           free(dict[j-1];
           dict[j-1] = NULL;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Not me, but shouldn't the commented-out line be `dict[i] = dict[j-1];` and then a `break;` instead of the `swapped` business?

Comment: @Weather Vane see the beginning of the answer **I do not check if the function does what it should**, only removed the UBs as an example approach. He is learning programming - lets try to find errors in his logic himself

Comment: Well, you are `free`ing the wrong memory - not the matching item.

Comment: the one where NULL is then assigned. Same as in the previous comment. Only have removed the memory leak, nothing else. We are not his teachers. Only answer the question asked.